# A way to ping selenium hub to see if node is available?

Tags: selenium, docker-compose, selenium-grid

Does anyone have a shell script or know of a way to ping a selenium hub to see if Nodes are available. Like a way to use [wait-for](https://github.com/eficode/wait-for/blob/master/README.md) or [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) or another way to check the Selenium Hub for a node before triggering a test?

EDIT: A specific node with a browser version available. So for example if the hub has Chrome 64 attached and Chrome 63 is connecting I'm trying to ping the hub until the Chrome 63 node attaches to the hub and is available for use.

Answer (score 0):

There is an endpoint in the Selenium Hub that can give you some of this info.

> > way to check the Selenium Hub for a node before triggering a test

Do a `GET` to `http://your-hub-here:4444/grid/api/hub` and you should see the free/total `slotCounts` (look at `newSessionRequestCount` to see queued tests). It doesn't have the granularity to show different browsers but you can get overview to determine if your grid is saturated.

Or if you are using [Selenium Grid Extras](https://github.com/groupon/Selenium-Grid-Extras) there would probably be an API behind their webview, that you would call to get the number of available browsers.

Comment: Sorry I should've worded this more specifically. I'm pinging the hub for a specific node, not if the hub has availability. I'll edit it. You answer is likely very use able to some, but I need to see if a specific browserVersion is available. Like keep pinging the Hub until Chrome 63 is available and not version 64.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you run docker on your local machine `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/status`

Here is a general from `http://{location}:4444/wd/hub/status`